# how to read json file without using json libarary or without any other libarary in to dictionary or list?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file and i need to read it into dictionary or list without using and library.This is my file content.

```
{
   "101":"Break and Enter Commercial",
   "102":"Break and Enter Residential/Other",
   "103":"Vehicle Collision or Pedestrian Struck (with Fatality)",
   "104":"Vehicle Collision or Pedestrian Struck (with Injury)"
}
```

This is what i try

```
def read_codes(filename):
    jsonData = {}
    # empty list to append to it later
    file = open(filename, "r")
    for key in file:
        print(key)
    return jsonData
print(read_codes('codes.json'))
```

Comment: Without library, you should implement parser of JSON. You can see JSON grammar from here: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Any reason why you do not wish to use a library?

Comment: I recommend to use library. But if you cannot(is it homework?), try to implement parser by yourself, and if you stuck somewhere, then ask about that here.

Comment: `data = eval(open(<path-to-file>, 'r').read())` that simple one liner alone is all you should need. Simple. This works because JSON syntax for simple data structures is the same as the Python syntax for dictionaries and lists. You don't need to loop over the file line by line, or do any string replacements. done.

Comment: I should mention a caveat with passing json directly to eval though. It's potentially, maybe only barely, a security risk to parse json received from untrusted sources this way. you should only do it with your own project's files. And it's proper form to use the json module anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. Please be careful with this though. You wouldn't want to be passing data submitted from web pages directly to `eval()` for instance. You should really consider using the json module just for security diligence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open it as a text file. It would return you list, then filter the list as you require.

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
    json_obj = jsonFile.readlines()
json_obj = [(obj.rstrip()).lstrip()[:-1] for obj in json_obj[1:-1]]
print(json_obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

What about such way:

```
with open(file) as f:
    your_dict = eval(f.read().replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: you don't even need the string replacement.